# Can't mount exported directory as NFS version 4

Tags: nfs, mount, nfs4

I'm trying to create a simple NFSv4 export. What I did so far:

My `exports` file:

```
/srv/nfs4 <myipnet>/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,fsid=0,no_subtree_check)
/srv/nfs4/homes <myipnet>/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

I also created a bind like it should be done for NFSv4 in `fstab`:

```
/home/nfshomes /srv/nfs4/homes none  bind  0 0
```

Then on my client I added this line to the `fstab` file:

```
server.example.org:/srv/nfs4/homes /media/nfshomes nfs rw,nfsvers=4 0 0
```

The mount works, I can see the files and everything; BUT it's mounted as NFSv3! The output from `nfsstat -m`:

```
/media/nfsv4homes from server.example.org:/srv/nfs4/homes
 Flags: rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=<ipaddr1>,mountvers=3,mountport=55778,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=<ipaddr2>
```

So can you tell me what I did wrong?

Manual mounting doesn't work either:

```
root@client:/media/nfsv4homes# mount -t nfs –o vers=4 server.example.org:/srv/homes /mnt/nfshomes
mount: bad usage
Try 'mount --help' for more information.
```

edit: After setting `RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids --no-nfs-version 3"` in the `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` file the mount is not working anymore (or empty). So it seems that the server falls back to NFSv3, which I disabled, hence no exports at all. So why does the server fall back?

Answer (score 0):

Okay the solution is quite simple.
The fstab line should be like this:

```
server.example.org:/homes /media/nfsv4homes nfs4 rw,defaults 0 0
```

Mounting works too:

```
mount server.example.org:/homes /mnt/nfshomes
```